# Error 2014 MySQL. Commands out of sync, when i create my first trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I am creating a database of information about application stores and well, I wanted to venture to create my first trigger, but something in my syntax fails (I am new to programming) and the terminal returns the 2014 error commands out of sync.

I put you in context: I have created 2 tables, 'Empleados'(employees) and 'Empresas'(company), with relation N: N, this has created another table of the relationship between these entities which is 'TRABAJAN'(work), there, I've put the Start Date (Fecha_inicio) in the company and the End Date(Fecha_fin), and also, I've put another column with boolean values on whether they are working or not. When I inserted the data I allowed that if they continued working, they had a NULL value.

Well, what I want is to create a trigger that when modifying the status of the working column from 1 to 0, I modify the NULL value of the Date_fin column by the value of the current system date.

I leave you the code and the trigger attempt I made:

```
CREATE DATABASE Info_Tiendas_App2;
USE Info_Tiendas_App2;

CREATE TABLE Empleados (
codEmpleado SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
DNI VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
NomEmpleado VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Calle VARCHAR(30),
Numero NUMERIC(3,0),
CodPostal NUMERIC(5,0),
CorreoElect VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Empresas (
codEmpresa SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
NomEmpresa VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PaisFacturacion VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
AnnoCreacion NUMERIC(4,0),
Correo VARCHAR(50),
PagWeb VARCHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE TRABAJAN (
codEmpleado SMALLINT,
codEmpresa SMALLINT,
Fecha_inicio DATE,
Fecha_fin DATE,
Trabajando BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY (codEmpleado, codEmpresa), 
FOREIGN KEY (codEmpleado) REFERENCES Empleados(codEmpleado)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (codEmpresa) REFERENCES Empresas(codEmpresa)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);

-- Aquí el trigger
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Mod_fecha_fin;
CREATE TRIGGER Mod_fecha_fin
AFTER UPDATE 
ON TRABAJAN
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF TRABAJAN(Trabajando) = 0 
UPDATE INTO TRABAJAN(Fecha_fin) SET Fecha_fin = (NOW())
ELSE
SET Fecha_fin = NULL
END //
```

Why do I get that error? What would I have to modify ?, and one last query, is the trigger well designed?

Thank you very much everyone for your help and time, greetings

Comment: *IF TRABAJAN(Trabajando) = 0* ??? Does `TRABAJAN` is a function?

Comment: no, its a table but his column Trabajando, has boolean values

Comment: Please look carefilly how the column of a table is specified in the query.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach that avoids triggers; consider using a calculated/derived column: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

```sql
CREATE TABLE TRABAJAN (
   codEmpleado  SMALLINT
 , codEmpresa   SMALLINT
 , Fecha_inicio DATE
 , Fecha_fin    DATE
 , Trabajando   BOOLEAN AS (CASE WHEN Fecha_fin IS NULL THEN b'1' ELSE b'0' END),
);
```

When `Fecha_fin` is `NULL`, the value of `Trabajando` is set to `true` (`b'1'`).

When `Fecha_fin` is `NOT NULL`, the value of `Trabajando` is set to `false` (`b'0'`).

i.e. when there's an end date set, they are considered to not be working. If there's no end date, they are considered to be working.

All you then have to do is update the value of `Fecha_fin` e.g.:

```sql
UPDATE TRABAJAN
SET    Fecha_fin = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE  codEmpleado = 937
AND    codEmpresa = 123
AND    Fecha_fin IS NULL
;
```

Comment: How i Have to insert the values in that column? It returns me Error 3105, the value specified for generated column 'Trabajando' in table 'trabajan' is not allowed

Comment: Hi @AbelPérez you don't need to insert into the `Trabajando` column in this set up. It's value is automatically derived from the value in `Fecha_fin`.

Comment: can you see my new answer to this post? thank you very much

Comment: I have tried to insert the data like this: INSERT INTO TRABAJAN(codEmpleado,codEmpresa,Fecha_inicio,Fecha_fin) VALUES (001,004,'2017/02/19','2019/07/23');

but it gives me this error: Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '\ x00' for column 'Working' at row 1

Comment: Hi @AbelPérez - I recommend you read the documentation linked in my answer. You cannot insert a value in to a generated column.